# Android: Slow reading of txt file and memory leak when inserting data into trie (wrong hashmap usage)?

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks, hashmap

I'm trying to read a 816 KB txt file (70 000 lines) in my android app which is contained in the res/raw folder. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
            InputStream raw = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.alpha);
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(raw);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String line;

            int j = 0;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null && j < 90000){
                theTrie.insert(line);
                j++;
            }
```

The "context" is given via a parameter: Main.readDatabase(getApplication());

This version crashes with the following log:

```
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xce48
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   | sysTid=1327 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006528
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   | schedstat=( 3112456663 436561269 431 )
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace(Native Method)
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:135)
10-04 21:14:26.096: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:74)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:38)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:36)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:34)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:-1)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:162)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at snappy.keyboard.TrieNode.<init>(TrieNode.java:21)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at snappy.keyboard.Trie.insert(Trie.java:27)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at snappy.keyboard.Main.readDatabase(Main.java:356)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at snappy.keyboard.SoftKeyboard.onCreate(SoftKeyboard.java:89)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:982)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-04 21:14:26.106: INFO/dalvikvm(1327):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 21:14:26.196: WARN/dalvikvm(1327): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;)
10-04 21:14:26.326: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(1327): Clamp target GC heap from 25.881MB to 24.000MB
10-04 21:14:26.326: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1327): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 13% free 20224K/22983K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-04 21:14:26.446: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(1327): Clamp target GC heap from 25.856MB to 24.000MB
10-04 21:14:26.446: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1327): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 25K, 13% free 20198K/22983K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 123ms
10-04 21:14:26.446: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1327): Shutting down VM
```

If I don't run this code (slightly changed due to file reading) in the emulator but in a normal java application it runs fine without any problems but on Android there seems to be a memory leak? Does somebody have any idea what could be the problem?
Even if I delete the line "theTrie.insert(line);" so that the while loop is (nearly) empty the app needs 2,1 seconds for "readlining" the 800 kb. This can't be normal, right? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I dumped a heap file with DDMS and analyzed it with MAT. It says: The class [in question], loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4051d5e8", occupies 23.951.808 (91,76%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[]" loaded by "".
The histogram lists java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[], java.util.HashMap and java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry as the three objects with the largest shallow heap.

Here is my code regarding the hashmap use (in the class thats defining the node of the trie):

```
public Map<Character, TrieNode> children;

public TrieNode(char letter) {
    this.letter = letter;
    children = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>(26);
}
```

Whats causing the memory leak?

Comment: I'm actually most curious about the `BufferedReader`. On `ObjectOutStream` you need to call `reset()` on it so it throws out all the references that its storing in memory. I would try the `Scanner` class just to see if it has a better memory management inside of it. 

Also, the reason why it crashed is cause your emulator's heap size is 24MB and (at least my) phone's heap size is 48MB. That's why it had an out of memory exception on one but not the other

Comment: I googled and it seems as you don't need to reset() or clear() the BufferedReader. I guess I have to live with the speed. But the memory leak in the trie stays. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Sometimes the emulator is not so much accurate than some of we would want** . Sometimes some process which runs nicely in a terminal , runs slow in emulator .

Try it with an android's phone and then don't forget to tell us with your experience.

-------------------------------------------- **MODIFY**

Try this:

```
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.alpha)));
        String line = null;

        int j = 0;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null && j < 90000){
            theTrie.insert(line);
            j++;
        }
```

And then see how many times do you call this function , maybe that's the problem.

**But , thinking about and seeing trie map , i can tell you too make an invest about what are you reading ,maybe the lines are too long** .

-------------------------------------------- **MODIFY 2**

I think the best you can do is change the point of view and try to use a SQLite db to have so much info and without problems of memory.

Comment: Ok, I ran it on my HTC Desire and "readLining" takes 900 ms. I don't know if this is normal but I think it's ok for the user as long as the dictionary stays in RAM for a while.
But: The memory leak stays! The program crashes with the line theTrie.insert(line);. I guess there is a real problem which wasn't perceivable on my PC due to its high RAM. Any ideas how I could find the memory leak? Are there any good tools out there?

Comment: I'm afraid your modification doesn't change anything. Am I missing something or do you just give the new variables directly as arguments instead of creating them? The time it needs is identical to my previous attempt :/ And the out of memory exception stays.
My trie has approximately 300 000 nodes and each node has got a hashmap in order to put and get its children. Maybe this is just too much for a phone... I'm not sure if it's a memory leak or just impossible to implement *such* a trie on a smartphone.

Comment: Sorry, for the very late answer. I've been quite busy. Meanwhile, I tried using simple arrays instead of hashmaps and now it doesn't crash anymore (no out of memory exception). But it's terribly slow :S Guess I have to rethink my concept. SQLite could be an option but I don't know how to save a trie in a SQLite database. Time will tell. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort!!